Error promise timeout when running whatsapp bot
I'm encountering an issue when running my WhatsApp bot using the Baileys library. Every time I try to use the "pppanjang" feature to change or set the WhatsApp profile picture, I receive the following error:


Error: Timed Out

    at C:\Users\HP G4O\Downloads\platform-tools\ryo2\node_modules\@whiskeysockets\baileys\lib\Utils\generics.js:136:32 {

      data: {

        stack: 'Error\n' +

          '    at promiseTimeout (C:\\Users\\HP G4O\\Downloads\\platform-tools\\ryo2\\node_modules\\@whiskeysockets\\baileys\\lib\\Utils\\generics.js:131:19)\n' +

          '    at waitForMessage (C:\\Users\\HP G4O\\Downloads\\platform-tools\\ryo2\\node_modules\\@whiskeysockets\\baileys\\lib\\Socket\\socket.js:114:53)\n' +

          '    at Object.query (C:\\Users\\HP G4O\\Downloads\\platform-tools\\ryo2\\node_modules\\@whiskeysockets\\baileys\\lib\\Socket\\socket.js:136:22)\n' +

          '    at okta (C:\\Users\\HP G4O\\Downloads\\platform-tools\\ryo2\\oka.js:1829:12)'

      },

      isBoom: true,

      isServer: false,

      output: {

        statusCode: 408,

        payload: {

          statusCode: 408,

          error: 'Request Time-out',

          message: 'Timed Out'

        },

        headers: {}

      }

    }

}

This happens when I send the message "pppanjang" which is supposed to configure WhatsApp profile settings. However, I always get this timeout error.
Has anyone encountered this issue before or know what might be causing it? Any help would be appreciated!
I tried using the "pppanjang" feature, which is supposed to set the WhatsApp bot's profile picture. I expected the bot to update the profile picture successfully, but instead, I encountered a "Timed Out" error. This happens every time I send the "pppanjang" command.

perhaps there's a bug in your code?

I've reviewed my code and couldn't find any apparent bugs so far. The error seems more related to a timeout issue when using the "pppanjang" feature of the bot. If you have any specific areas of the code you think might be causing this, I'd be happy to take a closer look. I appreciate any further insights you might have.

No, I have no more information to give
